# How to extract this element from a huge string output?

Tags: php, regex, string

I've tried doing this with regular expressions and preg_replace, but I'm just notoriously horrible with regular expressions.

```
<div class="eab-guest-actions"><a href="#cancel-attendance" class="eab-guest-cancel_attendance" data-eab-user_id="COULD BE ANYTHING" data-eab-event_id="COULD BE ANYTHING">Cancel attendance</a></div>
```

Anyone have some tricks, steps to doing this, or handling regular expressions?

Comment: [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument) can do this without regex. Do not use regex to parse HTML. Also, what is "this element" in your context? The entire string? Out of what?

Comment: It's markup used within a Wordpress widget that gets displayed, but the only hook I have to use dumps the widgets complete contents into my lap, and I just want to remove this functionality from the user.  But the string changes in those two spots so I can't just str_replace.

Comment: I'm still not sure what exactly you're trying to match.  The whole div element and everything inside it?  All div elements with class="eab-guest-actions"?  As the other commenter said, regex is not well equipped for parsing HTML/XML.  It's possible if the code has enough expected features, but you're probably better off using DOM one way or another.

Comment: "*those two spots*" What two spots? Are you talking about the attributes `data-eab-user_id` and `data-eab-event_id` of the `.eab-guest-cancel_attendanc` element?

Comment: Yah, those two capitalized strings could be anything and any length. So I was trying to make it skip over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
$pattern = '~<div class="eab-guest-actions">.*?</div>~s';
$str = preg_replace($pattern, '', $str);
```

or this (more performant):

```
$pattern = '~<div class="eab-guest-actions">(?>[^<]++|<(?!/div>))*</div>~';
```

If you want to be more precise:

```
$start = '<div class="eab-guest-actions"><a href="#cancel-attendance" class="eab-guest-cancel_attendance"';

$pattern = '~\Q' . $start . '\E(?>[^<]++|<(?!/div>))*</div>~';
```

details:

`\Q...\E` is used to escape possible special characters, this is usefull to put a literal string.

```
(?>             # open an atomic group
    [^<]++      # all that is not a <
  |             # OR
    <(?!/div>)  # a < not followed by /div>
)*              # repeat the group zero or more times.
```

Comment: Wow, that works great!  I can see the utility of regex, but I've always found them confusing, I can barely follow this.  Are you able to explain the last pattern briefly?

Comment: @mtpultz Perhaps you'd like [Debuggex](https://www.debuggex.com/r/eXNgx-xQzWmml65T).

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to read the `data-eab-user_id` and `data-eab-event_id` attributes of the `a` element, you can do so using [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument):

```
<?php
    $html = '<div class="eab-guest-actions"><a href="#cancel-attendance" class="eab-guest-cancel_attendance" data-eab-user_id="USERIDHERE" data-eab-event_id="EVENTIDHERE">Cancel attendance</a></div>';

    $userID = $eventID = null;

    $document = DOMDocument::loadXML($html);
    $xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
    $elements = $xpath->query("a[@class='eab-guest-cancel_attendance']");
    if (!empty($elements)) {
        foreach ($elements as $element) {
            $userID = $element->getAttribute('data-eab-user_id');
            $eventID = $element->getAttribute('data-eab-event_id');
        }
    }

    var_dump($userID, $eventID);
    //string(10) "USERIDHERE"
    //string(11) "EVENTIDHERE"
?>
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/cieitgZu)

Note how we use `loadXML` instead of `loadHTML` as this isn't full HTML.

Comment: What the performance difference between regex and DOMDocument.  This is super useful, but might be a bit of overkill.  I will definitely use this in the future no matter what.

Comment: @mtpultz The difference is that this would work until the `a` element didn't have that class any more, or until the attributes didn't exist. The regex solution relies on a very exact HTML string being returned (and regex can't say "give me the element with this ID, and show me its name attribute"). It should also be noted that regex has problems with huge strings from time to time.